# One ListView isn't scrollable in AnimatedCrossFade

Tags: android, listview, dart, scrollable, flutter

I'm new in flutter development and I have a problem:
I create new AnimatedCrossFade and add two different ListView to first and second child, but always one child ListView scrollable. How can I do scrollable ListView in first and second child?

(Same situation with simple GridView.)

Comment: Only one listview is scrolling that is your problem na?

Comment: Can you please add some code? It's hard to help you without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in [`AnimatedCrossFade`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedCrossFade-class.html). I filed an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10168).

You can work around it by not using `AnimatedCrossFade` and building your own animation using `FadeTransition`. Source code is below. Click the play button, it will start like this

[image: blue]

and end like this:

[image: red]

You can fade back and forth by clicking the button again. Both lists are scrollable and it remembers your scroll position.

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() => new MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Key _key1 = new GlobalKey();
  Key _key2 = new GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = new AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(Key key, Color color, double opacity) {
    return new Opacity(
      opacity: opacity,
      child: new Container(
        // Keep the hidden ListView around to maintain its scroll position
        // but set its height to 0.0 so it can't interfere with touches
        height: opacity == 0.0 ? 0.0 : null,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: color),
        child: new ListView(
          key: new GlobalObjectKey(color),
          children: new List.generate(
            100,
            (index) => new Text('Item $index'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          child: new Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
          onPressed: () {
            if (_controller.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed ||
              _controller.status == AnimationStatus.reverse) {
              _controller.forward();
            } else {
              _controller.reverse();
            }
          },
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Container(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
            child: new AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _controller,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              return new Stack(
                children: [
                  _buildList(_key1, Colors.red[200], _controller.value),
                  _buildList(_key2, Colors.blue[200], 1.0 - _controller.value),
                ],
              );
            }
          ),
        ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
}
```